# Setting the view height containing a scroll view with react native

Tags: react-native, view, height, scrollview

I am trying to set a scroll view inside a view and setting a auto height to this view to full fit the parent content. Everything is wrapped inside a `ImageBackground`.

```
<ImageBackground source={{uri : 'url'}} style={{height: 350, width: null, flex: 1}}>
    <View style={{flex: 1, height: 310}}>
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}>
            <View style={{flex : 1}}>
                <Text>
                    Simple text
                </Text>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    </View> 
<ImageBackground/>
```

Actually, the height of the view is : `height: 310` but it's supposed to be something like : `height:'auto'` to fill the whole parent content which is in my case the `ImageBackground`.

Comment: Have you tried setting: `width: '100%'`? If you want the width of the phone then you can use: `width: Dimensions.get('window').width` (You'll need to import Dimensions if you use the second one: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions)

Answer (score 0):

try this
 width: '100%'
 you can read the doc here
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions